# Zoom window for new documents to full screen

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller

This should be straightforward but I couldn't find anything on either SO or Google on this topic so..

**What's the best way of zooming new document windows to full screen** (i.e. not the *full screen mode* but just *maximizing* the window) for `NSDocument` based apps?

It might even be some method to override in `NSDocument` or `NSWindowController` but I'm unable to locate it. Or are we supposed to do this manually somewhere in the `initWithType:error:` method..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `performZoom:` to simulate clicking your window's green "Zoom" button.

Your window gets the zoom size from `windowWillUseStandardFrame:defaultFrame:`. Return a modified `NSRect`, there, to zoom to a size other than the default zoomed frame.

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    [self.window performZoom:self];
}

- (NSRect)windowWillUseStandardFrame:(NSWindow *)window defaultFrame:(NSRect)newFrame {
    // Implement a custom zoomed window size here, or return the default zoomed size.
    return newFrame;
}
```